# Returning a local pointer in C

Tags: c

```
const char* returnStr()
{
    char time[40] = {"France"};
    char* time1;

    time1 = time;

    return time1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])    {
    printf ("return String is %s\n",returnStr());
}
```

This code returns some junk characters. Won't the `const char*` not enough to return the local char pointer? Do I have to use the static too in the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have to use the static too in the function?

Yes. The `const` is just a qualifier on the return value, signaling to callers of `returnStr` that they shouldn't modify the result of the function. It doesn't change `time`'s temporary character.

Answer (score 4):

When the returnStr function terminates, its stack frame is deallocated - so whatever any local pointers point to is now random data. If you want to return a pointer, you have to allocate it on the heap, with malloc for example.

Answer (score 3):

The `time` object will exists only until `returnStr` is running.  Once it returns to the function that called it, it is gone, and any pointer to it is invalid.  In short, in C you cannot return an array from a function, you can only return a pointer to one.  This is why standard library C functions do not allocate strings at all, you must pass in a string and specify how large it is and it will fill it or error out.